# Repointing Datasource of layers using ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#

I'm currently working on a ArcObjects C# project that will repoint datasources for layers of various types. Basically a database is maintained that holds the old datasource connections and the new connections. When the user presses a button, the application goes through all the current layers in ArcDesktop and compares the layers current datasource with the new one. If there is a difference, it resets the datasource.

However, I'm not quite sure how to access the datasource, and in my perusings of this stackexchange, I [noticed someone](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22872/how-to-change-datasource-of-a-raster-in-sde-using-arcobjects) who was working on something similar, but they were using raster layers. I'm not too familiar with ArcGIS and didn't know if I needed to handle feature layers differently as he mentions he already found a solution for feature layers.

Here's the section I'm trying to change in ArcDesktop:[image]

I have everything working just fine except the changing of those datasources. I found [this resource on arcgis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000002r000000), but it doesn't appear to change those strings, though I could be mistaken.

This is what I currently have:

```
//Loop through all layers and get their information
pEnumLayer.Reset();
pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next();
while (pLayer != null)
        {
            Log.Debug("Manipulating the layer: " + pLayer.Name);
            IDataLayer dataLayer = (IDataLayer)pLayer;
            var datasource = dataLayer.DataSourceName; // this is what I believe to be the current datasource

            Log.Debug("Repaired layer: " + pLayer.Name);
            pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next();
        }
```

Is that the correct datasource I'm looking for? If so, would all I need to do to change the datasource is to set that variable to the new datasource string and then redraw the map?

Comment: I think you need to dig deeper to the featureLayer.FeatureClass level and then as the link you posted notes to use the IMapAdmin2.FireChangeFeatureClass Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esri's online help, there are examples of this problem, you can refer to this example.

URL:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000002r000000

Answer (score 2):

You should use IDataSourceHelperLayer Interface:

Code Snippet:

```
IDataSourceHelperLayer dsh = new DataSourceHelper() as IDataSourceHelperLayer;
dsh.ReplaceName(pLayer, newIName, false);
```

You can also use [IDataSourceHelperLayer.FindAndReplaceWorkspaceNamePath](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/001200000t06000000.htm) method.